# Access local host from another machine on network in rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

According to this [post](http://forum.railsonmaui.com/t/why-is-my-rails-4-2-app-not-available-on-my-local-network/227), in order to access the local server from another machine on the same network, you need to use 0.0.0.0:3000 as the address for localhost in rails 4.2. If I start the server with `rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000` I can indeed access from another machine, using the host ip address followed by :3000. However, the assets are not displaying. I have tried setting `config.asset_host = '0.0.0.0:3000'` in development.rb and restarting the server but this does not help.

So how do I have the assets load from a remote machine?  The console shows the following errors

```
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/application.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
192.168.0.57/:24 
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
192.168.0.57/:83 
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/infographic.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
192.168.0.57/:106 
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/analysis-thumb.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
192.168.0.57/:121 
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/chart-thumb.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
localhost:3000/images/favicon.ico:1 
GET http://localhost:3000/images/favicon.ico net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
gingerEditor.min.js:21 
Running Ginger Widget  version 0.1.0.585
localhost:3000/images/favicon.ico:1 
GET http://localhost:3000/images/favicon.ico net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

In this case, the host machine was at 192.168.0.57:3000.  The server log says the page loaded at 192.168.0.9 i.e. `Started GET "/" for 192.168.0.9`

Comment: Why don't you try binding to host IP instead of 0.0.0.0 ie.  rails s -b <host_IP> -p 3000

Comment: I tried that, thank you, but the assets still do not load.

Comment: Try to call directly some assets file on the remote server, maybe if you re running in production environment, your webserver does not serve static assets ....

Comment: Could it be asset pre-compiling problem? why don't you try `rake assets:precompile`. Although in development environment it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I tried ```rake assets:precompile``` and this did not help.  I am almost certainly running in development mode, config/environments/development.rb is executed when server starts up.

Comment: I tried loading an image on the remote server by typing in its url and it did load.  However, when I try to load a web page, there is no styling, and the images do not load.  I cannot see any error messages in the log. One strange thing is that the address for the host is 192.168.0.56 but in the log, it says it is loading the page from 192.168.0.5. If I try 192.168.0.5:3000 safari says it cannot load page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by setting the config.asset_host to the address of the host machine. So if the host machine is `192.168.0.17` then in `config/development.rb` you want the following line:

```
config.asset_host = '192.168.0.17:3000'
```

This is not ideal, it means you need to change your `development.rb` file every time you want to open up your development server by binding it to `0.0.0.0:3000`.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a `LINUX` or `UNIX` distro, open terminal and hit

```
ifconfig
```

Then find inet address like eg.

```
inet 192.168.0.113 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

Then from another machine in same network, you can hit below in browser

```
192.168.0.113:3000
```

Now you will able to run your application from different machine.

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: I have tried that and the web site loads but the assets do not.

Comment: are doing it in `development env`? please try to use this  `config.serve_static_assets  = true` in `development.rb`.

Comment: I tried config.serve_static_assets=true but that did not help.

Comment: Ok. Please open browser's console & clear errors, then refresh page and post here list of errors.

Comment: Good idea. I could not format the output properly in a comment, so have added it to the main question above.

Comment: Thanks. Does remote machine having any firewalls enabled? Have to tried same `IP` & `port` on different machine or mobile?

Comment: For this purpose, no firewalls are enabled and have tried on a Mac and an Iphone.   Do you know what the numbers like /:24 mean at the end of ```GET http://localhost:3000/assets/application.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
192.168.0.57/:24 ```?